# Клик на HtmlElement

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема. Я разбиваю htmldocumnet из webbrowser на отдельные htmlelemet-ы и для каждого создаю ивент клик, но проблема в том, что при одном клике по веб браузеру данный ивент срабатывает несколько раз(около 10). Как избавиться от данной фантомности?

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        HtmlElementCollection tags = webBrowser1.Document.All;

        foreach (HtmlElement element in tags)
        {
            element.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(element_Click);
        }
    }
void element_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e){...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что событие `click` "всплывает" - обработчики (у кого они есть) вызываются для всех элементов в цепочке родителей. Избежать этого можно, вызвав метод объекта `event` `stopPropagation` - в javascript, или в Вашем случае:

```
private void element_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
  e.BubbleEvent = false;
}
```

*Пример в javascript*

```js
$(".outer").click(function(e){
  console.log("in outer");
});

$(".letBubble").click(function(e){
  console.log("in inner - let bubble");
});

$(".stopBubble").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("in inner - stop bubble");
});
```

```css
.inner {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  background-color:red;
  width:200px;
  height:60px;
}

.outer {
  padding:10px;
  background-color:green;
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner letBubble">let click event bubble to parent</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="inner stopBubble">stop click event on this element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, можете чуть детальней объяснить.